# Duda POO. Como acceder a este método?

Tags: poo, java-8

Hola tengo las siguientes clases Java 8.

Quiero acceder al método `AgregarArticulo()` pero en el diagrama uml me lo marca en rojo y desde el `main` no me deja acceder a ese método, solo al método ordenar puedo utilizar pero antes de ordenar necesito agregar los artículos.
Cual seria la manera correcta de usar el método `AgregarArticulos()` ?

[image: Diagrama UML]

Esto es lo que marca eclipse cuando quiero usar el método

> "The method AgregarArticulo(Articulo) is undefined for the type List"

```
public class Articulo implements Comparable<Articulo>{

    protected String nombre;
    protected float precio;

    public Articulo() {
        super();
    }

    public Articulo(String nombre, float precio) {
        super();
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public float getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(float precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Articulo o) {
        if (getPrecio() < o.getPrecio()) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (getPrecio() > o.getPrecio()) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;

    }

}
```

---

```
public class ListaArticulos {

    List<Articulo> lista = new ArrayList<Articulo>();

    public ListaArticulos() {
    }

        public ListaArticulos(Articulo articulo) {
            AgregarArticulo(articulo);
        }



        private void AgregarArticulo(Articulo articulo) {
            lista.add(articulo);

        }

        public void ordenar() {
            Collections.sort(lista);
            for (Articulo articulo : lista)
                System.out.println(articulo.toString());
        }
    }
```

---

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List <Articulo> listaArticulos= new ArrayList<Articulo>();

        Articulo a1= new Articulo("Coca-cola", 64);
        Articulo a2= new Articulo("Coca-cola", 18);

        listaArticulos.AgregarArticulo(a1); //Acá quiero usar el metodo AgregarArticulo()


    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDITO:

Perdona no habia visto todo el objeto por que faltaba un {}

Para que puedas acceder a `AgregarArticulo` tienes que usar tu clase `ListaArticulos`:

```
    Articulo a1= new Articulo("jamon",22);
    Articulo a2= new Articulo("Coca-cola", 18);

    ListaArticulos misArticulos = new ListaArticulos();
    misArticulos.AgregarArticulo(a1);
```

Una vez introducido en nuestra lista esta listo para mostrarlo!

```
System.out.println("Nombre del articulo: " + misArt.lista.get(0).nombre  +  "  precio: " + misArt.lista.get(0).precio);
```

Comment: Gracias, entiendo lo que dices lo cambie a publico el metodo AgregarArticulo() pero sigo sin poder acceder a él, y antes cree la instancia del array asi List <Articulo> listaArticulos= new ArrayList<Articulo>();

Comment: @DiegoF. perdona habia leido mal el código, con la actualizacion ya podras llamar a ese metodo.

Comment: Hola Capt.Teach me podrias ayudar por favor con esta pregunta, que es sobre el mismo codigo pero esta vez con el metodo toString()  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/282260/m%c3%a9todo-tostring-java-8