# Método toString() Java 8

Tags: poo, string, java-8

Deseo imprimir los metodos `toString()` en este orden

[image: Asi es como quiero que imprima]

pero mis clases java me lo están imprimiendo de la siguiente manera y sé que el error esta en los metodos `toString()`que no los esta sobreescribiendo las clases hijas.
Así es como se imprimen en el código que publique en esta pregunta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: Diagrama UML del proyecto Java]

---

```
public class Articulo implements Comparable<Articulo> {

    protected String nombre;
    protected double precio;
    protected Unidad unidad;

    public Articulo() {
    }

    public Articulo(String nombre, double precio, Unidad unidad) {
        super();
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.precio = precio;
        this.unidad = unidad;

    }

    public void setUnidad(Unidad unidad) {
        this.unidad = unidad;
    }

    public Unidad getUnidad() {
        return unidad;

    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public double getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(double precio2) {
        this.precio = precio2;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Articulo o) {
        if (getPrecio() < o.getPrecio()) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (getPrecio() > o.getPrecio()) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        NumberFormat us = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
        return "Nombre: " + getNombre() + " /// " + " Precio: " + us.format(getPrecio())+ " /// " + getUnidad().toString();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Fruta extends Articulo {
        public Fruta() {

        }

        public Fruta(String nombre,double precio,Unidad unidad) {
            setNombre(nombre);
            setPrecio(precio);
            setUnidad(unidad);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            NumberFormat us = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
            return "Nombre: " + getNombre() + " /// " +" Precio: " + us.format(getPrecio())+ " /// " + getUnidad().toString() ;
        }



    }
```

---

```
 public class Cosmetico extends Articulo {

        public Cosmetico() {
                }

        public Cosmetico(String nombre, double precio, Unidad unidad) {
            setNombre(nombre);
            setPrecio(precio);
            setUnidad(unidad);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            NumberFormat us = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
            return "Nombre: " + getNombre() + " /// " +  getUnidad().toString() +"ml" +" /// "  +" Precio: " + us.format(getPrecio());
        }


    }
```

---

```
public class Bebida extends Articulo {

    public Bebida() {
    }

    public Bebida(String nombre, double precio, Unidad unidad) {
        setNombre(nombre);
        setPrecio(precio);
        setUnidad(unidad);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        NumberFormat us = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
        return "Nombre: " + getNombre() + " /// " +  getUnidad().toString()+" /// "  +" Precio: " + us.format(getPrecio());
    }

}
```

---

```
   public class ListaArticulos {

        List<Articulo> lista = new ArrayList<Articulo>();

        public ListaArticulos() {
        }

        public ListaArticulos(Articulo articulo) {
            AgregarArticulo(articulo);
        }



        public void AgregarArticulo(Articulo articulo) {
            lista.add(articulo);

        }

        public void imprimirArticulos() {
            for (Articulo articulo : lista)
                System.out.println(articulo.toString());

        }
    }

    public enum Unidad {

            KILO("unidad de venta: ","kilo"), LITRO("Litros:",1.5), ML("Contenido:",500);

            private String unidad;
            private String kilo;

            private double cantidad;

            private Unidad(String unidad, double cantidad) {
                this.unidad = unidad;
                this.cantidad = cantidad;
            }


            private Unidad(String unidad, String kilo) {
                this.unidad = unidad;
                this.kilo= kilo;
            }


            public String getUnidad() {
                return unidad;
            }


            public String getKilo() {
                return kilo;
            }


            public double getCantidad() {
                return cantidad;
            }



            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return   getUnidad() + "" + getCantidad() ;
            }


        }
```

---

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Articulo a1 = new Articulo("Coca-cola Zero", 20,Unidad.LITRO);
        Articulo a2 = new Articulo("Coca-cola", 18,Unidad.LITRO);
        Articulo a3 = new Articulo("Shampoo Sedal",19,Unidad.ML);
        Articulo a4 = new Articulo("Frutillas",64,Unidad.KILO);

        ListaArticulos listaArticulos = new ListaArticulos();
        listaArticulos.AgregarArticulo(a1);
        listaArticulos.AgregarArticulo(a2);
        listaArticulos.AgregarArticulo(a3);
        listaArticulos.AgregarArticulo(a4);

        listaArticulos.imprimirArticulos();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si te fijas en la clase `Articulo` tienes el metodo `toString()` al reves.

Tu método:

```
  return "Nombre: " + getNombre() + " /// " + " Precio: " + us.format(getPrecio())+ " /// " + getUnidad().toString();
```

Según lo que buscas debería de ser así :

```
    return "Nombre: " + getNombre() +  " /// " + getUnidad().toString() +  " /// " + " Precio: " + us.format(getPrecio());
```

---

EDIT:

El problema reside en que el Enum `Unidad` si te fijas no tiene `getKilo()` en el `toString()`, por que lo que nunca podrás recuperar lo.

Usando el siguiente código podrás recuperar los kilos/Cantidad según lo que necesites:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getUnidad()  + "" + (getCantidad() ==0 ? getKilo() : getCantidad() ).toString();
}
```

Si la cantidad es 0, es decir que llamas a este constructor `private Unidad(String unidad, String kilo)` recuperare el valor de Kilo, si la cantidad es diferente a 0 entonces llamo al otro constructor `private Unidad(String unidad, double cantidad)` y recupero la cantidad.

Para que no te den nulos tienes que editar los dos constructores tal y como te dejo aquí:

```
private Unidad(String unidad, double cantidad) {
    this.unidad = unidad;
    this.cantidad = cantidad;
    this.kilo = "";
}


private Unidad(String unidad, String kilo) {
    this.unidad = unidad;
    this.kilo = kilo;
    this.cantidad=0;
}
```

Cualquier cosa me dices.

Comment: Si eso si un error de orden pero a esto me refiero precisamente Nombre: Frutillas /// Precio: $64 /// Unidad de venta: kilo y me imprime  a mi esto Nombre: Frutillas ///  Precio: $64.00 /// unidad de venta: 0.0

Comment: osea en vez imprimirme el string "kilo" del enum me imprime "0.0" y en shampoo sedal que es de la clase cosmetico me imprime 500 y no "500 ml"

Comment: @DiegoF. voy a editar mi pregunta con lo que me pides

Comment: Gracias Capt una ultima duda como hago para que esto que me imprime ahora Nombre: Frutillas /// unidad de venta: kilo ///  Precio: $64.00 pero yo quiero que quede Nombre: Frutillas /// Precio: 64.00 // unidad de venta: kilo

Comment: Deberia sobreescribir el toString() de la clase Fruta y utilizar ese en vez el de Articulo,no?

Comment: @DiegoF. Una cosa que yo cambie es que en el Main, no creo objetos Articulo como tu `Articulo a4 = new Articulo("Frutillas",64,Unidad.KILO);` yo los creo como lo que son `Fruta a4 = new Fruta("Frutillas",64, Unidad.KILO);` ya que al fin y al cabo Articulo es el padre. Si lo haces así puedes sobrescribir el `toString()` de cada clase por separado, dando le un formato personalizado según tus necesidades

Comment: Ya entendi genial, marco como respuesta correcta :D

Comment: @Capt.Teach eso es un error, pierdes el sentido de la clase padre. Hay que crearlos usando la interfaz como destino -> `Articulo a4 = new Fruta(....)`